# Multiline UL List

Tags: css

I have a list with 6 items, I want the list the be multicolumn so, on the first column it will show the first 3 items and on the second column the following 3 items and so on...
But I really can't understand how to create this behavior using an UL.. I tried playing with the options for example setting the UL `{height:50%;}` but with no results

This is a basic fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/n8f7hxzo/

I know I can use a table but I don't want to, Just wanted to know if there's a simple solution about this problem

Comment: do you need like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n8f7hxzo/2/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8f7hxzo/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: didn't knew about this property, gotta find a fallback for i.e.<10 though :P thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use css columns like http://csswizardry.com/2010/02/mutiple-column-lists-using-one-ul/ should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `display:inline-block` in order to display your items horizontally.

Adding a width to your LI's (by exemple 33%), it will work.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8f7hxzo/1/)

Comment: The problem with this is that I need them in order so first column
aaa
bbb
ccc
and this just puts them inline